# Emacs opens ibuffer or compilation in same window rather than other window

Tags: emacs

I have been using emacs for many years.  The past year or so, there has been an annoying problem, which is that sometimes Ibuffer or the compilation buffer runs in the same window that I am already in.  I generally have 2 buffers open, one above the other.  I always want Ibuffer to open in the one I am not currently in.  But it seems to pick randomly.  Is this a bug or feature?  Can I stop it?  I have searched for an answer several times, but I have not found one.  I am running GNU Emacs 24.5.1 in the terminal. Thanks.

Comment: Is the other window strongly dedicated by any chance and that's why your current window gets selected instead?  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html  You might want to test the other window.  How about opening up the `ibuffer.el` source code and looking for the code responsible for displaying the buffer -- `M-x find-library RET ibuffer RET` -- you'd be looking for something like:  `(if other-window-p (funcall (if noselect (lambda (buf) (display-buffer buf t)) #'pop-to-buffer) buf) (funcall (if noselect #'display-buffer #'switch-to-buffer) buf))`

Comment: How about customizing the variable `ibuffer-use-other-window` -- which has a doc-string that states:  *"If non-nil, display Ibuffer in another window by default."*  The default vale is `nil`.  I would suggest that you consider editing/limiting this question to `ibuffer` and open a new question (if Google has no hits) for the `compilation` window -- my guess is that there are probably quite a few threads for the `compilation` window, but I haven't looked myself.

Comment: Customizing the ibuffer-use-other-window does not seem to help.  To reproduce, I am starting emacs with `emacs .` and then doing `^x-b` and then hitting n to get the cursor to *scratch*, hitting return to open *scratch*, then doing `^x-b` again.  It opens the ibuffer in the same window as *scratch*, leaving the top window with the dir listing and the bottom window with *scratch*.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer relates to the usage of `ibuffer`:

The original poster may wish to use the keyboard shortcut bound to the letter `o`, which is `ibuffer-visit-buffer-other-window`.  The doc-string states that this function is designed to:  *Visit the buffer on this line in another window.*  The function `ibuffer-visit-buffer-other-window` uses `pop-to-buffer` and `switch-to-buffer-other-window`, which should avoid a window that is dedicated:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html

The return key is bound to `ibuffer-visit-buffer` (which uses `switch-to-buffer`), and the doc-string states that this function is designed to:  *Visit the buffer on this line.  If optional argument SINGLE is non-nil, then also ensure there is only one window.*  The optional argument can be used interactively by typing `C-u RET`.

Comment: I do use both enter and o in ibuffer, and both of those work well.  What is not working for me is when I am opening ibuffer, and it opens in the current window instead of the other one.

Comment: Is it possible you just want?:  `M-x ibuffer-other-window` instead of `M-x ibuffer`.  The doc-string for `ibuffer-other-window` states:  "*Like `ibuffer`, but displayed in another window by default.  If optional argument FILES-ONLY is non-nil, then add a filter for buffers which are visiting a file.*"

Comment: I am using ibuffer-other-window